# Converting string objects to int/float using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

path1 = "/home/supertramp/Desktop/100&life_180_data.csv"

mydf =  pd.read_csv(path1)

numcigar = {"Never":0 ,"1-5 Cigarettes/day" :1,"10-20 Cigarettes/day":4}

print mydf['Cigarettes']

mydf['CigarNum'] = mydf['Cigarettes'].apply(numcigar.get).astype(float)

print mydf['CigarNum']

mydf.to_csv('/home/supertramp/Desktop/powerRangers.csv')
```

The csv file "100&life_180_data.csv" contains columns like age, bmi,Cigarettes,Alocohol etc.

```
No                int64
Age               int64
BMI             float64
Alcohol          object
Cigarettes       object
dtype: object
```

Cigarettes column contains "Never" "1-5 Cigarettes/day","10-20 Cigarettes/day".
I want to assign weights to these object (Never,1-5 Cigarettes/day ,....)

The expected output is new column CigarNum appended which consists only numbers 0,1,2
CigarNum is as expected till 8 rows and then shows Nan till last row in CigarNum column

```
0                     Never
1                     Never
2        1-5 Cigarettes/day
3                     Never
4                     Never
5                     Never
6                     Never
7                     Never
8                     Never
9                     Never
10                    Never
11                    Never
12     10-20 Cigarettes/day
13       1-5 Cigarettes/day
14                    Never
...
167                    Never
168                    Never
169     10-20 Cigarettes/day
170                    Never
171                    Never
172                    Never
173                    Never
174                    Never
175                    Never
176                    Never
177                    Never
178                    Never
179                    Never
180                    Never
181                    Never
Name: Cigarettes, Length: 182, dtype: object
```

The output I get shoudln't give NaN after few first rows.

```
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      0
5      0
6      0
7      0
8      0
9      0
10   NaN
11   NaN
12   NaN
13   NaN
14     0
...
167   NaN
168   NaN
169   NaN
170   NaN
171   NaN
172   NaN
173   NaN
174   NaN
175   NaN
176   NaN
177   NaN
178   NaN
179   NaN
180   NaN
181   NaN
Name: CigarNum, Length: 182, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Are you sure row 10 and 11 actually equals 'Never' and that there isn't a space or other character in the value?

Comment: Yes,I didn't check the space till now.Really thanks.Could you help me with an efficient way to ignore these spaces.I have lot more columns with space in the beginning.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

OK, first problem is you have embedded spaces causing the function to incorrectly apply:

fix this using vectorised `str`:

```
mydf['Cigarettes'] = mydf['Cigarettes'].str.replace(' ', '')
```

now create your new column should just work:

```
mydf['CigarNum'] = mydf['Cigarettes'].apply(numcigar.get).astype(float)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Jeff as always for pointing out superior ways to do things:

So you can call `replace` instead of calling `apply`:

```
mydf['CigarNum'] = mydf['Cigarettes'].replace(numcigar)
# now convert the types
mydf['CigarNum'] = mydf['CigarNum'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

you can also use `factorize` method also.

Thinking about it why not just set the dict values to be floats anyway and then you avoid the type conversion?

So:

```
numcigar = {"Never":0.0 ,"1-5 Cigarettes/day" :1.0,"10-20 Cigarettes/day":4.0}
```

**Version 0.17.0 or newer**

`convert_objects` is deprecated since `0.17.0`, this has been replaced with [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric)

```
mydf['CigarNum'] = pd.to_numeric(mydf['CigarNum'], errors='coerce')
```

Here `errors='coerce'` will return `NaN` where the values cannot be converted to a numeric value, without this it will raise an exception

Comment: you can use ``series.replace(dict)`` I believe to do the substitution, then ``convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`` to change to float (forcibly); you can also ``factorize`` to make categoricals (e.g. map the strings to numbers)

Comment: @Jeff so is `replace` faster than calling `map` or `apply` and passing a dict now? Wasn't aware of `factorize` also, when was this introduced?

Comment: replace should be much faster; ``factorize`` has been their quite a while (but not advertised :))

Comment: @EdChum Hi, when I do this I get "A value is trying to be set on copy of a slice from a Dataframe" how do I change original dataframe?

Comment: @h_musk please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas basically if you want to operate on a copy then you should call `df.copy()`, otherwise follow that link if you want to operate on a view

Answer (score 4):

Try using this function for all problems of this kind:

```
def get_series_ids(x):
    '''Function returns a pandas series consisting of ids, 
       corresponding to objects in input pandas series x
       Example: 
       get_series_ids(pd.Series(['a','a','b','b','c'])) 
       returns Series([0,0,1,1,2], dtype=int)'''

    values = np.unique(x)
    values2nums = dict(zip(values,range(len(values))))
    return x.replace(values2nums)
```

Comment: That's nice! Minor comments: requires _import numpy as np_; desired add-on: optionally, assign -1 or something like that for null values if such occur